# What is going on with this balanced paren problem? getting no results and no error

Tags: python, stack, structure

I'm not getting any error or any results so I can't quite pinpoint the issues.
It's based on the 'stack' data structure.

```
def is_match(p1, p2):
    return (p1,p2) in ['(,)', '{,}', '[,]']

def is_open(param):
    return param in '([{'

def is_balanced(exp):
    stack = []
    for i in range(len(exp)):
        if is_open(exp[i]):
            stack.append(exp[i])
        else:
            top = stack.pop()
            if not is_match(top,str(exp[i])):
                return False

    if stack == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False


is_balanced('{[}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are not printing anything. Your function always returns `False`, but without a `print`, the result is discarded.

Secondly, you have logic errors. The most obvious one is `('(', ')')` is never equal to `'(,)'`. And if you don't test if the stack is empty as you pop, so in case of input such as `'}'`, you will get an error. And `str(exp[i])` is redundant, `exp[i]` is a string already. Finally,

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is an antipattern; you can simply say `return condition` (or, if it is not a boolean and you want it to be, `return bool(condition)`; not needed in this case, as the result of equality comparison is always a boolean).